# build_absolute_uri inside model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls, django-2.0

I'm using Django 2.0

In my application's models.py file I have defined `get_absolute_url()` to get the absolute URL of the instance.
This model class is used as URL shortener and stores a `short_key`.

This will produce url like

```
http://short_domain/key
```

the short url host domain can bet set from settings.

If the `SHORT_URL_HOST` exists in `settings`, that will be used otherwise current website domain/host will be used.

I'm using `{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}` to display the generated short url.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import request

class ShortUrl(models.Model):
    short_key = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        reverse_url = reverse('short-url', kwargs={'key': self.short_key})
        if hasattr(settings, 'SHORT_URL_HOST'):
            url_host = settings.SHORT_URL_HOST
        else:
            url_host = request.build_absolute_uri("/").rstrip("/")

        return url_host + reverse_url
```

`If` is working fine. But in `else` statement, I want to get complete `URI` of current host concatenated with the reverse URL.

But this gives error as

```
module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'
```

**How can I return full absolute URI with domain name from model's `get_absolute_url(self)` function?**

Comment: Your model doesn't (shouldn't) know anything about requests, that should be handled in the view layer. Indeed where does `request` even come from in this method? If you want to do conditional redirection you should do that in the view and you'll have a request object in scope.

Comment: I thought of that importing django request might work. I want `{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}` to print full url including domain in the template

Comment: Why don't you expand the detail of your question to show more of what it is you are trying to achieve. Post: model, view, template (fragments) and summarise the issue. There will be a solution to your problem but I suspect you are kind of swimming against the current of how Django works.

Comment: I have summarised the question a little. Hope it will make some sense.

Comment: @jhrr What about the case when sending an email from signals or model method and you want a link for the user to change a specific model?